# Restlet ServerResource Get request implem with FileRepresentation triggers a jetty.io.EofException on "big" files (approx. more than 100 KBytes)

Tags: jetty, restlet

I have got a restlet Application on top of an embedded Jetty server.
One ServerResource implements the HTTP Get request through represent() method.
We expect the URL to be formed like that : server:port/model?id=345

```
        @Get
        public Representation represent() {
                    String id = getQuery().getFirstValue("id");
                    Representation result = null;

                    Model model = daoFactory.getModelDao().findById(id);
                    File modelFile = model.getFile();

                    FileRepresentation fr = new FileRepresentation(modelFile, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, -1);
                    result = new InputRepresentation(fr.getStream(), fr.getMediaType());

                    setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_ACCEPTED);

                    return result;
        }
```

When the request is performed (i tried with both text and binary file) the http connection is closed by the server which displays the following traces

```
        déc. 15, 2015 5:10:30 PM org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter commit
        GRAVE: An exception occured writing the response entity
        org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:408)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:364)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:111)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.processKey(SelectorManager.java:636)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:607)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.run(SelectorManager.java:545)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.NonBlockingThread.run(NonBlockingThread.java:52)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
                    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172)
                    ... 10 more

        2015-12-15 17:10:30.972:WARN:oejs.Response:qtp20590698-20: Committed before 500 An exception occured writing the response entity
        déc. 15, 2015 5:10:30 PM org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper handle
        AVERTISSEMENT: Error while handling an HTTP server call: 
        déc. 15, 2015 5:10:30 PM org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper handle
        INFOS: Error while handling an HTTP server call
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1253)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:567)
                    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.internal.ServletCall.sendResponse(ServletCall.java:397)
                    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter.commit(ServerAdapter.java:214)
                    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:153)
                    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1118)
                    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:245)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Implementing the same code with a text file (json) and MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON does work but only for small files (approx. under 100KBytes)

Comment: I set up a new project and made a Restlet with a similar `represent()` method but failed to reproduce your exception.

Comment: I will try with a more recent restlet version and submit a complete sample if I still experience the trouble.